# No appropriate method, property, or field 'time' for class 'Simulink.SimulationOutput'

Tags: matlab

I send the structure variable time from Simulink to the workspace with this code but I received this error when I use MATLAB 2016a but in MATLAB 2018b I didn't receive any error :
No appropriate method, property, or field 'time' for class 'Simulink.SimulationOutput'.

```
simOut = sim(mdlName,'SrcWorkspace','current');
stop_time=simOut.time.signals.values(end);
```

Comment: Hi, please make sure the title of your post is a clear question. Also, you have not provided enough detail for people to reasonably be able to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, in my file Simulink I use to workspace block that connected to clock because I need the value of time to finish a loop in my code. And I save the value of time in stop_time variable but I get this error: No appropriate method, property, or field 'time' for class 'Simulink.SimulationOutput'.                                                         My version MATLAB is 2016a and I guess this notation (simOut.time.signal.values) is not appropriate for the version 2016a